# External HD with a Filevault 1 home directory, readable from Lion?

Tags: external-disk, filevault

I have the HD from my old Snow Leopard Mac containing my old home directory encrypted with Filevault 1.  Can I mount this HD in a USB enclosure as an external volume on a new Mac running Lion, and read the contents of my old Filevault 1 protected home directory?  Do I need a Keychain item, or anything other than my old login password or admin password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. I've used this to recover data from an old Macbook Pro hard disk when I couldn't boot the computer itself using a SATA-to-USB caddy.

Once the old drive is attached, first you need to locate the `.sparsebundle` file containing your encrypted home directory on your old hard disk. This lives in a hidden folder

`/Users/.<username>/<username>.sparsebundle`

in my case this would be

`/Users/.binarybob/binarybob.sparsebundle`

Once you've found this, you can mount it using the terminal with

`hdiutil attach binarybob.sparsebundle`

You will be prompted for your password. Once you've entered it correctly, your home directory will be mounted and visible as a drive from the Finder (and rooted  at `/Volumes/binarybob`)